# boot() equivalent in python?

Tags: python, statistics-bootstrap

Is there an equivalent of [boot and boot.ci](https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html) in python?
In `R` I would do

```
library(boot)
result <- boot(data,bootfun,10000)
boot.ci(result)
```

Comment: You might want to look at the [scikits.bootstrap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.bootstrap) package. But it would probably be helpful to potential answerers to this question if you explain what R's `boot` and `boot.ci` do (or at least link to appropriate R resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can point to specific bootstrap usage in python. I am assuming you are looking for similar methods for bootstrapping in `python` as we do in `R`.

```
import numpy as np
import bootstrapped.bootstrap as bs
import bootstrapped.stats_functions as bs_stats

mean = 100
stdev = 10

population = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=stdev, size=50000)

# take 1k 'samples' from the larger population
samples = population[:1000]

print(bs.bootstrap(samples, stat_func=bs_stats.mean))
>> 100.08  (99.46, 100.69)

print(bs.bootstrap(samples, stat_func=bs_stats.std))
>> 9.49  (9.92, 10.36)
```

The specific packages used here are `bootstrapped.bootstrap` and `bootstrapped.stats_functions`. You can explore more about this module [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bootstrapped/0.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

There's also the `resample` package available via `pip`.  Here's the Github page: https://github.com/dsaxton/resample.

Regarding your example you could do the following (there's also a `ci_method` argument you can tweak for either the percentile, BCA or Studentized bootstrap interval):

```
from resample.bootstrap import bootstrap_ci

bootstrap_ci(a=data, f=bootfun, b=10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's now also a `bootstrap` function in the `scipy.stats` module [scipy.stats.bootstrap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bootstrap.html)

Comment: Hi Riccardo C., welcome to SO. While the information in your link may solve the OP's question, link-only answer are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained with a minimal amount of code so others can verify that it works. Thanks